# Is there a method to approximately predict a 3D curve given two plane view of the curve?

Tags: prediction, interpolation, information-extraction

[image: Data]

Let's say the original data contains three variables, so it is a list of (x,y,z). In the figure, the blue and red curves are the lists of (x,z1) and (y,z2), respectively. These two lists are obtained by using digitizer from an image in a pdf document, therefore z1 is not the same as z2. I need a few (x,y,z) points which are sufficient to represent the whole curve.

I may be able to manually extract points which have the same z from both blue and red curves. But in fact, my data contains five variables and there are many to be done. I am not relevant to this field, I am thinking if there is any technique to deal with this problem.

Here is the link to the data. The first column of each two is the independent variable, the second column is the shared variable.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19dFZrd-uRJhVDG05-t38GbAM9r0cMSArJXzwThn3riY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is difficult, if not impossible, to determine how that graphic might be related to your data.  Could you show us a few lines of the data and explain how the graphic represents them?